# JS exponential curve fit

Tags: javascript, math, curve-fitting

I'm trying to make a simple function to do an exponential curve fit given a dataset.  I've written the following:

```
  function expCurveFit(d){
    var sum_x2 = 0, sum_lny = 0, sum_x = 0, sum_xlny = 0, n = d.length;
    for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++){
      var x = d[i][0];
      var y = d[i][1];
      sum_x2 += x^2, sum_lny += Math.log(y), sum_x += x, sum_xlny += x*Math.log(y);
    }
    var a = ((sum_lny*sum_x2)-(sum_x*sum_xlny))/((n*sum_x2)-sum_x^2);
    var b = ((n*sum_xlny)-(sum_x*sum_lny))/((n*sum_x2)-sum_x^2);
    return [a,b];
  }
```

but a and b don't seem to be correct.  I'm working from the basic formula at [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html).  The inputted array is in the form `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...[xn,yn]]`.  Anyone have working suggestions, plug-ins, libraries, or revised functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[^ is the XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) in JavaScript, not exponentiation.

Replace `x^2` with `Math.pow(x,2)` or `x*x` and do the same for both places where you have `sum_x^2`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) as marked as the answer for this question, there's a mistake on the **a** and **b** coefficients.

The curve that you will fit using this method is `Y = B * exp(A * x)`, as is written in [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html), but `B = b` and `A = exp(a)`!

So you have to change the return `[a,b]` to `[ Math.exp(a), b]` (if you want to use this array as a "equation")

Comment: Wouldn't it be: `Y = A * exp(B * x)` ??